# Checking university license using structures in C language

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am working on a code which gets input from user and takes university name, license and area code.

Now user is asked for university to be searched and if found gives the name of university.

Also the license length should be 6 characters only and first 2 should be UPPERCASE letters while remaining four should be digits.

When I scan 3 university names it skips scanning the middle one. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with the code?

Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{  
   struct University
    {   
      char name[10];
      char li[6];
      int ar;
    }u[5];

char s[10];
int a,i,c=0,j,flag=1;

printf("Enter the number of records\n");
scanf("%d",&a);

if(a<=0)
printf("Unable to continue");
else
{
  printf("Enter the details of %d universities\n",a);
  for(i=0;i<a;i++)
   {
      printf("Name of the University\nLicense Number\nArea Code\n");
      scanf("%s %s %d",u[i].name,u[i].li,&u[i].ar);
      /*checking license length and its validity*/
      if(strlen(u[i].li)>6)
        c=c+1;
      for(j=0;j<2;j++)
       {
         if(u[i].li[j]<'A'||u[i].li[j]>'Z')
         c=c+1;

       }
      for(j=2;j<6;j++)
       { 
       if(u[i].li[j]<'0'||u[i].li[j]>'9')
       c=c+1;
       }
   }
if(c>0)
printf("Sorry! You have entered incorrect license number.");
else
   {
    printf("Enter the name of the University to be searched\n");
    scanf(" %s",s);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
      {
       if(strcmp(s,u[i].name)==0)
       flag=0;
      }
    if(flag==0)
    printf("University is licensed one.");
    else
    printf("University is not found.");}
    }
    }
```

Comment: I hav the feeling that the [mcve] for this could be smaller...

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: 1) `char li[6];` --> `char li[6+1];` or more.

Comment: please post formatted code in the future too.

Comment: you forgot about ending zero. Your char arrays are too small.